# css background цвет на 2 раздела

Tags: css

[image: 1]
Должно быть так

[image: 2]

у меня без закругления желтый цвет подскажите пожалуйста.

```css
.start {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: 'Poppins Regular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 200px;

}

.start_text {
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(254,170,37,1) 12%, rgba(226,234,237,1) 12%, );
```

```html
<section class="start">


            <div class="start_text">
                <div class="start_icon"></div>

                <h1 class="start_text_glav"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>#1 Editiors Choice App of 2020</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: У вас в вопросе обрезан `css` код. Пожалуйста дополните его.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.start {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-family: 'Poppins Regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.start_icon {
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.start_icon svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
}

.start_text_glav {
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>2bg</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="start">
    <div class="start_icon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-patch-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path fill="white" d="M10.354 6.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-1.5-1.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7 8.793l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
      <path fill="white" d="m10.273 2.513-.921-.944.715-.698.622.637.89-.011a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 2.924 2.924l-.01.89.636.622a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 0 4.134l-.637.622.011.89a2.89 2.89 0 0 1-2.924 2.924l-.89-.01-.622.636a2.89 2.89 0 0 1-4.134 0l-.622-.637-.89.011a2.89 2.89 0 0 1-2.924-2.924l.01-.89-.636-.622a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 0-4.134l.637-.622-.011-.89a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 2.924-2.924l.89.01.622-.636a2.89 2.89 0 0 1 4.134 0l-.715.698a1.89 1.89 0 0 0-2.704 0l-.92.944-1.32-.016a1.89 1.89 0 0 0-1.911 1.912l.016 1.318-.944.921a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 0 2.704l.944.92-.016 1.32a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 1.912 1.911l1.318-.016.921.944a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 2.704 0l.92-.944 1.32.016a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 1.911-1.912l-.016-1.318.944-.921a1.89 1.89 0 0 0 0-2.704l-.944-.92.016-1.32a1.89 1.89 0 0 0-1.912-1.911l-1.318.016z"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="start_text_glav">
      <h1>#1 Editiors Choice App of 2020</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Предложу такой вариант. На экранах не менее 900px в ширину выглядит вполне прилично.

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать отдельные свойства css для закругления границ:

```
.start_text {
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(254,170,37,1) 12%, rgba(226,234,237,1) 12%, );
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно вот так записать:

border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
/* top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left */